# Condition for uncorrelated two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, independence

[Edited: Since my previous question is not so clear, I changed my question.]

Let $X,Y$ be random variables in $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \mathbb{E}[XY] = 0.$$
If $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$, $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.
(However, if possible, I don't want to make zero mean assumption.)

**Here is my question:**
Based on the above information $\mathbb{E}[XY] = 0$, what other conditions are needed if one can conclude

If $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$, $X^i$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. Or without zero mean, 
$$ (*) \quad \mathbb{E}[X^iY]=0.$$

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$, $(*)$ satisfies. But this is too trivial.
And I am trying to find other conditions which makes $(*)$ true (even for $i=2$ or $3$). 
I am thinking about some conditions on the distributions of $X$ or $Y$.

Any comments or suggestions will be very appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

p.s. I am sorry for changing my question.

Comment: What kind of condition are you looking for?

Comment: I dont know what "else" you are looking for, but if $X,Y$ are correlated, then $Cor(X,Y) \neq 0$ and therefore $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = E[XY] \neq 0$...

Comment: @herbsteinberg My apology for the unclear previous question. I changed my question and it would be very appreciated if you can take a look again.

Comment: @antkam My apology for the unclear previous question. I changed my question and it would be very appreciated if you can take a look again.